# Is there a way to make netbeans navigate to Laravel 5 Facade classes?

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I'm using Netbeans to work on a Laravel 5 application, and Laravel 5 encourages you to define aliases (called Facades) for certain classes.
You can then extend these aliases in your class.

However, Netbeans IDE won't let you click-through (ctrl+click on classname) on these classes, since it only knows them by their original name. Is there a way to make this work?

Example:

app.php

```php
'aliases' => [
  ...
  'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
  ...
]
```

Procedure.php

```php
<?php
namespace LS\Domains\Procedure;

Class Procedure extends \Eloquent  {
  ...
}
```

In this example, netbeans is unable to navigate to the \Eloquent class from Procedure.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) it works for me with php storm